# ksoap2 transport.HttpResponseException: HTTP request failed HTTP status: 403

Tags: java, android, asp.net, soap

Context

- App in Java / Android Studio
- Web services in ASP.Net

Issue

- The web services work well from several cell phones, except one only. Error:

> org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException: HTTP request failed, HTTP
>   status: 403 at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call

The test is done from the same wifi connection.

It seems a specific cell problem. It has Android 7.0.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

all else phones out to the service with the same wifi too?
i have the exect problem while connect the same wifi with the service.
but when i turn off the wifi in the phone work fine.